# How do you add a user to edit a spreadsheet in .NET?

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I am using C# / .NET with the `Google.Apis.Sheets.v4` libraries (and other required Google Api libraries). I want to create a spreadsheet then add users to be able to access and edit that spreadsheet. I have been able to successfully create a spreadsheet but then I don't know how to access it since I don't know how to share it. I know that I have my credentials and other parts successfully set up because I can read and write to spreadsheet that I already have access to but I cannot figure out how to set/add those permissions through the library.

Here is what I currently have:

```cs
_sheetsService = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
     HttpClientInitializer = credential,
     ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
});

Spreadsheet newSpreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
newSpreadsheet.Properties = new SpreadsheetProperties() { Title= spreadsheetName };

// add view and edit permissions??

var result = _sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Create(newSpreadsheet).Execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to use Google Drive api as well to share spreadsheet, I can be wrong. At least, it worth trying it

I would say like as  below;

```
 List<string> emails = new List<string>(); // I assumed that there are some email list
 var driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

// Share the spreadsheet with specific users
        foreach (var email in emails)
        {
            Permission userPermission = new Permission()
            {
                Type = "user",
                Role = "writer", // or "reader" depending on the desired permission
                EmailAddress = email,
            };

            driveService.Permissions.Create(userPermission, result.SpreadsheetId).Execute();
        }
```